# BeautifulSoup: Combine consecutive <ul> lists

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a few rugged HTML files with lists wrongly split, like in the example below.

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>

<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

I need to combine each series of lists into one list. But **only consecutive lists**, so the first list (before `<p>`) is not mixed up with the second one (after `<p>`).

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>

<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Python code:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('ul'):
    previous_tag_list = tag.find_previous_sibling(tag.name)
    previous_tag = tag.find_previous().find_previous()
    if previous_tag_list is not None and previous_tag_list == previous_tag:
        for tag1 in tag.find_all('li'):
            previous_tag.append(tag1)
            tag.decompose()
```

For each `<ul>` it finds a previous `<ul>` and combines the two together. So I get this:

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>

<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "only consecutive lists"? Can you edit the question and add an example of a non-consecutive list and what it does to your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I edited the question, hope it's clear now!

Comment: I suspect your actual code contains more than two `<ul>` groups, and it has <p>` tags between each, right? Also, if that's true, is there a `<p>` before the first `<ul>` and/or after the last `<ul>` group?

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, the actual code contains multiple `<ul>` groups, and there are many different tags between those groups, not just `<p>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with plain `BeautifulSoup`:

```
txt = '''<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>

<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for ul in soup.select('ul ~ ul'):
    p = ul.find_previous_sibling()
    if p and p.name == 'ul':
        ul.extract()
        for li in ul.select('li'):
            p.append(li)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  Foo
 </li>
 <li>
  Bar
 </li>
</ul>
<p>
 Bla bla bla
</p>
<ul>
 <li>
  Foo
 </li>
 <li>
  Bar
 </li>
 <li>
  Baz
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a beautiful and extremely clean piece of code. Thank you so much Andrej!

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>

<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ul = doc.ul
while True:
    next = ul.next
    if not next: break
    if ul.tag == "ul" and next.tag == "ul":
        ul.setContent(ul.html + next.html)
        next.repleaceSelf("")
    else:
        ul = next
print(doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>

<li>Bar</li>
</ul>


<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<ul>
<li>Foo</li>

<li>Bar</li>

<li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `simplified_scrapy`, thanks! Will give it a shot.